# Implementing Local Passport Strategy for Hyperledger-Composer-Rest Server: "Cannot GET /auth/local","status":404

Tags: authentication, hyperledger-composer, passport-local

I'm trying to implement the Local Passport Strategy for Hyperledger Composer Rest Server.

To achieve this, I did the following:

First, I installed passport-local by running the following command:

```
npm install -g passport-local
```

In my home folder I created a file called "envvars.txt" with the following content:

```
COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{

    "local": { 
            "provider": "local", 
            "module": "passport-local", 
            "usernameField": "username", 
            "passwordField": "password", 
            "authPath": "/auth/local", 
            "callbackURL":"/auth/local/callback",
            "successRedirect": "/", 
            "failureRedirect": "/", 
            "setAccessToken": true, 
            "callbackHTTPMethod": "post" 
    }

}'
```

Then, in oder to set the environment variable COMPOSER_PROVIDERS, I ran the following command:

```
source envvars.txt
```

After that I started the composer-rest-server using the following specifications:

[image]

When I went to localhost:3000/explorer, http-requests were blocked (as expected) because I was not authenticated.

So far so good.

But when I tried to go to address localhost:3000/auth/local (in order to authenticate), this was not possible ... the web browser gave me an error message, the beginning of which was as follows:

```
{"error":{"statusCode":404,"name":"Error","message":"Cannot GET /auth/local","status":404,"stack":"Error: Cannot GET /auth/local\n    at raiseUrlNotFoundError
```

What went wrong here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are not persisting the data. In the `envvars.txt` you need to specify where to persist the data because right now there's no database to store the user and password.

Like explained in the [official docs](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server) you need to persist your data in MongoDB for example.